# C# tokenEdit 'Can't transform the 'a' part of 'a,b,c,d,e,f' EditValue in Tokens'

Tags: c#, devexpress

I use tokenEdit control and I want to set tokens from a string like below code:

```
string _MovieGenre = "a,b,c,d,e,f";
tokenEdit1.Properties.EditMode = TokenEditMode.Manual;
tokenEdit1.Properties.PopupFilterMode = TokenEditPopupFilterMode.StartWith;
string[] MovieGenrewords = _MovieGenre.Replace(", ",",").Split(',');
tokenEdit1.Properties.Tokens.Clear();
tokenEdit1.EditValue = string.Join(",", MovieGenrewords);
```

But I get this error :

```
'Can't transform the 'a' part of 'a,b,c,d,e,f' EditValue in Tokens'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve my problem with replace this code:

```
tokenEdit1.EditValue = string.Join(",", MovieGenrewords);
```

with the following code:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < MovieGenrewords.Length; i++)
                {
                    item = new TokenEditToken(MovieGenrewords.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    tokenEdit1.Properties.Tokens.Add(item);

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        tokenEdit1.EditValue = MovieGenrewords[i];
                    }
                    if (i > 0 && i < MovieGenrewords.Length - 1)
                    {
                        tokenEdit1.EditValue += "," + MovieGenrewords[i];
                    }
                    if (i == MovieGenrewords.Length - 1)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            tokenEdit1.EditValue += "," + MovieGenrewords[i];
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
```